# Strange scaling when duplicating monitors with another screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, resolution, scaling

I can't get two monitors to scale application resolutions the same way. My main monitor works normally. My second monitor however, which is set to duplicate its image onto a TV I have in my room, renders the applications in a far lower resolution than the 1080p I've set it to.
Also, the mouse pointer on the second monitor is enormous, it looks 2-3 times bigger than the one on the  main monitor.

I've checked the "Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays", to no avail.
Here are some comparison pictures.

Metro on the main monitor:

[image: image1]

Metro on monitor 2 (set to 1080p and to duplicate on a TV):

[image: image2]

And here's comparison pictures of the mIRC program on the two monitors:

[image: image2]

and then

[image: image2]

As you can see, the mIRC window is MUCH bigger on the secondary monitor, cause of how weird the scaling is.

I use a single Geforce 660 GTX and the OS is Windows 8.1.
The monitor is a BenQ G2420HDB, the TV is a Samsung UE46F5005.
This issue only seem to arise when I duplicate the monitor onto the TV.
Does anyone have any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: what's the native resolution of the second monitor?

Comment: Same as the main monitor, 1920*1080

Comment: What kind of graphics card do you have?

Comment: Also, how are you connecting to both these monitors? (DVI? HDMI? VGA?)

Comment: I use a Geforce GTX 660.
The main monitor and the secondary monitor is connected using DVI, the TV is connected using HDMI.

Comment: Just to be sure, could you hook up the TV to your computer using DVI (if supported) and hook the first monitor to your computer using HDMI and see what happens. Also, the model numbers and make of both the TV and the monitor might help.

Comment: I switched around, and still the same issue.
The monitor is a BenQ G2420HDB, the TV is a Samsung UE46F5005.

Comment: `"This issue only seem to arise when I duplicate the monitor onto the TV"` So you're saying this problem doesn't occur when you select "Extend" instead of "Duplicate?"

Comment: Also, [please read this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/when-using-multiple-monitors-my-main-screen-goes/930e1e5a-5de1-41cc-b87b-d112fa352a27) and see if the issue you're facing is the same

Comment: The problem has never occured before I got the TV and started to duplicate it, yes. I've always been able to use the dual monitors without any problems.
And no, I've don't have the lower resolution issue. http://i.imgur.com/7bDHQxO.png

Answer (score 0):

Can't be fixed. You can't scale 2 monitors differently. Down size the res of your highest monitor or buy 2 that match.

By having a check box that says "Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays" it implies there is another option. There is not. It does not work.